# OAuth google Api return null .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I was using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker but it dos not work after published,I changed to GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow but I'm getting null Token Response

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService GetService()
    {

        var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "-----",
                ClientSecret = "----"
            },
            Scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly, "email" },
            DataStore = new FileDataStore(Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/"), "DriveServiceCredentials.json"), true)
        });
        TokenResponse token = flow.LoadTokenAsync("user", CancellationToken.None).Result;       
            
              UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, "user", token);
              
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveRestAPI-v3",
            });   
  return service; 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: any solution ....?

Comment: Do you have your ```credentials.json``` file on the right directory to be accessed? Do you have a generated ```token``` file ? If so could you please remove it to see if a new token can be generated successfully? Have you followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) for authorization?

Comment: Yes I have credentials.json file on the right directory

Comment: I update the code

Answer (score 1):

To implement you OAuth 2.0 implementation in your web application of ASP .NET please follow the steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc). Considering that you have created your credentials successfully you would just need to adjust your `FlowMetadata` as described in the sample provided in the documentation (also considering that you have included the relevant packages for your application).

Please note that in this implementation it uses the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` rather than using the `credentials.json` file for authentification. For more information about user credentials handling in ASP .NET [check this piece of documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#user-credentials).